# How to show duplicate options in Activity diagram

Tags: uml

This Question has been asked and answered before, but i did not clearly understand the answer.
So here is the Question:
There is a condition "X". There are three steps A,B and C.
Irrespective of whether condition "X" succeeds or fails, A & B are available.But, "c" is available only if condition "X" succeeds.
I tried everything i know, but no use so far. Please Suggest something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can parallelize the activities A,B and C then you should introduce join/fork bars. If they wille be executed serialized it could like this

```
 O
 |
(A)
 |
(B)
 |
 /\ [X not succeeded]
 \/ -------+
  |        |
 (C)       |
  |        |
  O -------+

O Begin / End
(A) Aktivity A
/\
\/ Condition
Arrows have been omitted
```

See also uml tutorials on how to model control flow.

Comment: So many months later, i encountered the same issue again. This time, i found a better idea. Since one flow has an option additional to the other one, i split it into two use cases and used Extends dependency